# How to create new tf2::convert specialization?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, tf2, range, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Before you point me to tutorials, I've seen all the existing ones and have looked at tf2_eigen.h and tf2_bullet.h as examples. I created a new header file in my package, named tf2_range.hpp with contents:

```
namespace tf2
{
inline
geometry_msgs::PointStamped toMsg(const sensor_msgs::Range& in)
{
    geometry_msgs::PointStamped out;
    out.header.stamp = in.header.stamp;
    out.header.frame_id = in.header.frame_id;
    out.point.y = out.point.z = 0;
    out.point.x = in.range;
    return out;
}

inline
void fromMsg(const sensor_msgs::Range& in, geometry_msgs::PointStamped& out)
{
    out.header.stamp = in.header.stamp;
    out.header.frame_id = in.header.frame_id;
    out.point.y = out.point.z = 0;
    out.point.x = in.range;
}

}
```

In a cpp file in that package, I include the header and call tf2::convert(range, pointStamped), resulting in the error:

```
CMakeFiles/sensor_fusion_node.dir/src/sensor_fusion.cpp.o: In function `void tf2::convert<sensor_msgs::Range_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(sensor_msgs::Range_<std::allocator<void> > const&, geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> >&)':
sensor_fusion.cpp:(.text._ZN3tf27convertIN11sensor_msgs6Range_ISaIvEEEN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_IS3_EEEEvRKT_RT0_[_ZN3tf27convertIN11sensor_msgs6Range_ISaIvEEEN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_IS3_EEEEvRKT_RT0_]+0x1f): undefined reference to `void tf2::impl::Converter<true, true>::convert<sensor_msgs::Range_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >(sensor_msgs::Range_<std::allocator<void> > const&, geometry_msgs::PointStamped_<std::allocator<void> >&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/dev/src/rosws/devel/.private/sensor_fusion/lib/sensor_fusion/sensor_fusion_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sensor_fusion_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What's undefined about the way I'm handling this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290258/how-to-create-new-tf2::convert-specialization?/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2018-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Going to answer my own question here-- tf2 tutorials don't make it abundantly clear that you're not allowed to create a convert() specialization consisting of two ROS messages. Here's the reasoning (from tf2/impl/convert.h):

```
// The case where both A and B are messages should not happen: if you have two
// messages that are interchangeable, well, that's against the ROS purpose:
// only use one type. Worst comes to worst, specialize the original convert
// function for your types.
// if B == A, the templated version of convert with only one argument will be
// used.
//
//template <>
//template <typename A, typename B>
//inline void Converter<true, true>::convert(const A& a, B& b);
```

Not sure I agree with the design decision, but it's easy enough to write my own convert function for my specific purpose, so why argue?

---

Originally posted by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) with karma: 753 on 2018-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A [Point](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Point.html) and a [Range](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Range.html) message are not isomorphic. This is why they are in different messages. Your converters lose a lot of information going from the Range to a Point. Thus it's not a conversion but a projection. You should not create conversion methods like this that are not isomorphic. If there are two of these defined it's possible for the template logic to traverse through a pair of these and return completely invalid data.

I'd recommend that you write your function as `projectRangeToPoint` as you're dropping information and casting it down to just a point in 3D. If you were to write the inverse function you would need to add arguments to fill in the rest of the `Range` fields.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1